# how to configure Selenium c# with nightly builds(SpecFlow,Nunit,DotnetProject)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, nunit, specflow, octopus-deploy

I have automated UI tests with Selenium c#. It is a dotnet project.

**SpecFlow** to write the test cases and **Nunit** to run them.

We are using **Azure Devops** for storing the code.

**Octopus** is used for build and deployments.

I want to automate my tests with nightly builds. Which is a better options for the pipeline? Is it Azure DevOps or Octopus.

Please suggest which is the best way?, more steps and the process to start with it.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to automate my tests with nightly builds. Which is a better
> options for the pipeline? Is it Azure DevOps or Octopus.

For this issue, you can [configure scheduled trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) in azure devops pipeline.

Select the days and times when you want to run the build.
If your repository is Azure Repos Git, GitHub, or Other Git, then you can also specify branches to include and exclude.

[image]